# How to show parent and child term in autocomplete exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I created a view with autocomplete exposed filter and this is working fine. However, I need to show autocomplete in hierarchical mode.

For example, I have two locations:

1. phase-1
2. phase-1

The first phase-1's parent is Chandigarh, and second phase-1's parent is Delhi. But autocomplete filter shows only one phase-1.

Comment: You could an entity reference field and an entity reference view that joins those two fields into one title. So for the title in your entity reference view, have a hidden parent field above it and rewrite the title.

Comment: I am not getting. How its possible. I dont get any option to take this module.

Comment: Would you be happy with each taxonomy term being called "parent - term" in the autocomplete? I made up a quick view yesterday to test it but forgot to post it. I can later if it would be acceptable.

Comment: It would be great help.